# Seeking alternative site to GLC30/globeland30?

Tags: imagery, land-cover, service-recommendations

In 2014, China released a global land-cover data at 30m resolution, called GLC30 or globeland30.

I used it with success in some areas. But for some months now when I try to access the main download site [www.globallandcover.com](http://www.globallandcover.com), I got a time-out error.
[glc30.tianditu.com](http://glc30.tianditu.com/) is still accessible, though.

Does anyone know an alternative download site?

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for an alternative download site, or asking for the history, or something else?

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative download site if any, and if not, if there is any possibility the original website will be back online.

Comment: You should edit that into the question. Just click edit below the question.

Comment: Quick update 1/2017: the Globeland30 site is back: http://www.globallandcover.com/

Comment: The website is back, but the download requests don't seem to be answered. I made a request one week ago and so far I did not get any feedback.

Comment: Yes it seems to be working (april 2017)
I created a request, it took several days but they created an FTP with the tiles I requested.

Comment: Indeed, I tried some weeks ago and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I've sent a request recently, how long does it take (1 week?) to get their response?

Comment: @Vitruvius I've sent a request in April and I am still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Login was not possible for me on the English site, however, switching to Chinese (and guessing the few login steps) worked! After login, switching to English and downloading data is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Lijun Chen, who is the contact person for this dataset, what is happening and this was his reply:

> Because we are asking for the specific process of registration
>   authority to the relevant government departments, Once finish it, we
>   will run it again, so stay tuned.

So it seems the main website will be back online in due time but no idea when.